# Delete file names from folder with Variables

Tags: php, file, directory

I am trying to create this script that would delete the filename from a folder whose name is contained inside the $id variable.  NOt sure why its not working:

Code:

```
 unlink('/userstash/$id' . $fn);
```

Comment: What do `$id` and `$fn` contain exactly? What does a test output show you? (There might be a slash missing)

Comment: make sure you validate and sanitize your variables. nothing worse than `$fn = '/../../etc/passwd'`

Comment: @knittl yeah don't worry.  have that being checked.

Comment: @pekka you were right i was missing the "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this one

```
unlink("/userstash/$id$fn");
```

[single quotes don't parse variables inside](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Is there a reason you have not suggested to put `$fn` inside the string as well then?

Comment: hakre: I have no idea, I was posting it in hurry

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes, in other words:

```
unlink("/userstash/$id" . $fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take care that you properly build the string for your path and then add some error checking so your script informs you when something goes wrong and tells you about the filename:

```
$path = '/userstash/' . $id . $fn: 
$r = unlink($path);
if ($r === false)
{
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Unable to delete file "%s".', $path));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the double qoutes:

```
unlink("/userstash/$id" . $fn);
```